# Multiple firebase databases with one firebase authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I built a web platform that allows users to signup with one user account to multiple web apps. Each app has its own separate firebase database. Is it possible to use firebase authentication and to share the same authentication between the various firebase databases? I mean like single sign on to multiple firebase database via one user base.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please read [this recent blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/working-with-multiple-firebase-projects-in-an-android-app.html) on the [Firebase blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/).  It addresses various scenarios where all your data is not in a single project.